# Как перевести число из одной системы счисления в другую, и при этом не использовать вещественные типы данных

Tags: c, алгоритм

На вход в программу поступает два числа `b1` (изначальная система счисления) и `b2` (та в которую нужно преобразовать) и число `X` (максимум 13 символов), над которым все операции и будут проводится.

Понятное дело, что сначала надо бы перевести `X` в десятичную систему, и с реализацией перевода целой части проблем нет.
*(кстати вот она)*

```
//r1 - целая часть числа 
//char X[13];
for (; X[i] != 0 && X[i] != '.'; i++) {
    r1 = (('0' <= X[i] && X[i] <= '9') ? X[i]-'0' : (('A' <= X[i] && X[i] <= 'Z') ? X[i]-'A'+10 : (('a' <= X[i] && X[i] <= 'z') ? X[i]-'a'+10 : 0))) + r1*b1; 
}
```

Но вот как быть с дробной частью? *(повторюсь, вещественные типы запрещены)*

Думаю в сторону представления числа в виде обычной дроби (числитель/знаменатель).

Например преобразование 0.34 из восьмеричной системы в десятичную будет выглядеть так:

`3*8^(-1) + 4*8^(-2) = 8^(-2) * (3*8 + 4) = 28 / 64`

*Но пока из этой идеи ничего толкового так и не получилось.*

Подскажите алгоритм или просто идею для решения этой задачки.

з.ы.

Накидал примерный алгоритм. Получилось коряво, не очень рабоче, плюс по задаче возведение в степень не приветствуется. Но возможно, кого-нибудь это натолкнёт на верную мысль, коею он сможет помочь мне.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
 
int main(void) {    
    int p, tmp = 1, b1, b2, R1 = 0, R2 = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0, len, i = 0, j = 0, n = 1; 
    char X[13], ch;
    scanf("%d",&b1);
    scanf("%d",&b2);
    scanf("%s", X); if (X[0]=='-') i++; 
    len = strlen(X);  
    for (; X[i] != 0 && X[i] != '.'; i++) r1 = (('0' <= X[i] && X[i] <= '9') ? X[i]-'0' : (('A' <= X[i] && X[i] <= 'Z') ? X[i]-'A'+10 : (('a' <= X[i] && X[i] <= 'z') ? X[i]-'a'+10 : 0))) + r1*b1;   
    printf("%d",r1 );
    if (len == i) return 0;   
    else  printf(".");
    for (i++; X[i] != 0; i++, n = n*b1) r2 = (('0' <= X[i] && X[i] <= '9') ? X[i]-'0' : (('A' <= X[i] && X[i] <= 'Z') ? X[i]-'A'+10 : (('a' <= X[i] && X[i] <= 'z') ? X[i]-'a'+10 : 0))) + r2*b1; r2 = r2*10000000/n; 
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        p = pow(10, floor(log10(abs(r2)))+1) ;
        tmp = r2 * b2 / p; 
        r2 = r2 * b2 - tmp * p; 
        char ch = ((0 <= tmp && tmp <= 9) ? tmp+'0' : ((10 <= tmp && tmp <= 26) ? tmp +'A'-10 : 0));
        printf("%c",ch );
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: То, что справа от точки, может не быть представимо конечной записью. Типа выразите 0.2 в двоичном виде - это будет бесконечная дробь...

Comment: Я понимаю, что должно быть приближение. Но это все дело десятое и для меня понятное, в отличие от сабжа.

Comment: В современных процах вещественное число выглядит примерно как знак(старший бит)(порядок)(Мантисса), в памяти это набор бит и все зависит от их интерпретации 3.14 сохраненное в формате float никогда не совпадет с тем же числом в формате double. Поэтому, кстати, компилятор и будет сыпать ворнинги при сравнении значений разных типов данных. Если я, положим, захочу число из 10тичной системы счисления преобразовать в 8ричную или двоичную, то кроме как зафиксировав формат числа я никак по-другому не смогу выразить его в двоичном или любом другом виде.

Comment: т.к. сами эти форматы не предусматривают наличия десятичной точки. единственный вариант в этом случае умножать исходное число на  большое целое число, и хранить результат в другом представлении (с потерей точности) либо хранить отдельной целую часть и отдельно дробную как два целых числа. если конечно операция умножения целых чисел тоже не находится под запретом в исходных условиях задания.

Comment: вообще в стандартной библиотеке Си есть функция unsigned long strtoul(const char *start, char **end, int radix) обычно описанная в заголовочном файле stdlib.h натравив ее на твои данные исходные и указав СС ты на выходе сразу получишь целую часть числа. дробную она отбросит. затем найди десятичную точку через strstr() и скорми ее еще раз strtoul() получишь уже дробную часть числа как целое. результат можно всегда скормить atoi или atol и указав нужную СС получишь символьное представление на выходе. останется только придумать как его хранить.

Comment: @Yakov, у меня нет проблем с преобразованием строчки в число, или деления строчки на два числа с делителем в виде точки. Проблема заключается в переводе дробной части числа в другую СС. Ибо если хранить дробную часть как целое число, я без понятия как её переводить в разные СС.

Comment: ну если проектировщики процессоров и прочей вычислительной техники за почти восемьдесят лет не придумали лучшего решения кроме как фиксировать формат вещественного числа в двоичной СС, то я не думаю, что и ты что-то придумаешь принципиально новое. храни число в формате [целая часть][дробная часть][множитель]. Любое число можно представить как набор бит СС в данном случае всего-лишь означает сколько этих бит в одном разряде будет храниться в конечном представлении. всегда проще переводить в 2ю СС и затем переводить в любую другую. результат преобразования всегда полином

Comment: N += d*pow(base, index), если ты параметры такого полинома зафиксируешь, т.е. количество членов этого полинома, то результат от СС зависеть не будет. Проблема в том, что нет четкого соглашения о формате таких представлений, ну кроме форматов данных сопроцессора, и то архитектурно зависимых.

Comment: если у тебя скажем есть число 100, в десятичной СС то его можно записать в виде полинома 0*10^0+0*10^1+1*10^2, для перевода в другую СС тебе надо подобрать(разложить число) в полином результатом вычисления которого с другим значением основания вместо 10 например 16 будет тоже число. в 16й СС число 100 будет выглядеть как 4*16^0+6*16^1.

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь тебе объяснить, что это все-равно, что пытаться записать мнимую часть комплексного числа с помощью натуральных чисел не прибегая к расширенному алфавиту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея разложения и представления в виде дроби со знаменателем b1^n  в вопросе правильная, да и идея реализации по большому счёту тоже... но вот что дорогой OP за магию со знаменателем (`p`) пытался сотворить, я разобраться не рискну.

В причёсанном виде всё это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
int ch2n(char c) {
  if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
    return c - '0';
  } else if('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
    return c - 'a';
  } else if('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
    return c - 'A';
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}

char n2ch(int n) {
  if (0 <= n && n <= 9) {
    return '0'+n;
  } else if (10 <= n && n <= 35) {
    return 'A'+n;
  } else {
    return '?';
  }
}

int main(void) {

  // ...
  
  int p=1, r2=0;
  for( i++; X[i] != 0; i++ ) {
    r2 = r2*b1 + ch2d(X[i]);
    p *= b1;
  }

  for( i = 0; i < 10 && r2 != 0; i++ ) {
    tmp = (r2*b2) / p; 
    r2  = (r2*b2) % p; 
    putchar(d2ch(tmp));
  }
  return 0;
}
```